# My discord.py tasks.loop() is not executing

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this code that should send `Loop Check` every minute, but there is no output other than Flask, d.py and GET requests

Code:

```py
class infinityplus(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @tasks.loop(minutes=1)
    async def check_date():
        with open('giveaway.json', 'r') as rf:
            giveaway = json.load(rf)
        ctx = giveaway['ctx']
        message = giveaway['message']
        prize = giveaway['prize']
        today = date.today()
        date1 = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        print('Loop Check')
        if date1 == '22/10/2021':
            users = await message.reaction.users().flatten()
            winner = random.choice(users)
            embed2 = discord.Embed(
                title='Giveaway Ended',
                description=
                f'__**Winner**__: {winner.mention}\n__**Hosted by**__: {ctx.author.mention}',
                colour=red)
            await message.edit(embed=embed2)
            await message.channel.send(
                f'Congrats {winner.mention}, you won {prize}\n\nhttps://discord.com/channels/{message.guild.id}/{message.channel.id}/{message.id}\n({ctx.author.id})'
            )

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(infinityplus(bot))
```

Output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHdgO.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an error handler. Otherwise, if an error occurs in a task, it will pass silently.

```
import logging, traceback
async def on_error(event, *args, **kwargs):
    print('Something went wrong!')
    logging.warning(traceback.format_exc())
```

Comment: i have that in my main file